# Segmentation Visualisation DNN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, optimization, computer-vision

I was interested in what the network is exactly learning during the process of image segmentation. Take unet for example. In image classification, the hierarchy of features is more clearer to understand but here, what is the network representing in the most compressed stage in the mid conv layers? As the dimension(x,y) of image are very shrunk, what is the network storing here and then passing on? I want to gain a deeper intuition as to feature representation in image segmentation.